# How to remove the existing environment variable in Linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

This is my machine path :

```
~$ echo $PATH
```

> /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/sams/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin

Here, I want to remove all the paths related to rvm

[image]

---

I removed all the above lines from .bashrc and .bash_profile but still it exists in the GEM_PATH where else it is erased from the common PATH

[image]

Comment: Quite a few suggestions has been laid out for you on how to fix this now. Is the problem solved?

Comment: @mattias yes it is :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

check:
echo $PATH
```

you can add the export code inside .bashrc

Comment: I am unable to replace the existing one :(

Comment: my question is how to remove the existing path; please help me on this

Comment: check your .bashrc or .bash_profile  , see if the rvm path is added at that time.

Comment: its there in the .bashrc and .bash_profile. How can I remove it? Please check the image in the description

Answer (score 0):

You can manually overwrite your PATH through exporting it again, but that only affects the current session.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

If you want the change to last, you have to find where the rvm parts are added to the PATH variable. That's probably at the end of the `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile`, or `/etc/profile`, .. it depends on how you installed rvm) file. You can safely remove those lines that add rvm to the path.

In case you also want to uninstall rvm (which I suspect if you go the second route), do a

```
rvm implode
```

Comment: Hi @tessi I shouldn't want it for the current session; rather I need it permanently.

Comment: Then follow the second part of my answer. The `~/.bashrc` is really only a file. You can edit it with any text editor :)

Comment: let me uninstall rvm and check; Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look for alternations in the $PATH variable would be your .bashrc file. Look for something like:

> export PATH=/your/homefolder/.rvm:$PATH

Another thing worth asking, do you have this behaviour on startup of the system or is it just in one local shell window? If it's only in the current shell session (and not in the .bashrc or something similar), it will not stick/be permanent.

Comment: How to remove the path? please guide me

Comment: Can you give me the output of the 'export PATH..' line(s) in your .bashrc? Note, there might be more than one of them there.

Comment: If the graphic included above is a snippet from your .bashrc, just remove the first three lines, save the changes and type 'exec bash' followed by echo $PATH in your shell.

Comment: Yeah I did it and it has gone now

Comment: but even after that, the environment variable is not changed :( let me add the image

Comment: The $GEM_PATH is nothing you included in the beginning. You asked how to remove stuff from the $PATH environment variable. The process to remove stuff from your $GEM_PATH should basically be of same approach, try to find any occurrences of it in the .bashrc and remove what you want to remove, then save and reload the bashrc (exec bash)

Answer (score 0):

To remove Rvm, run

```
$ rvm implode
Are you SURE you wish for rvm to implode?
This will recursively remove /Users/gaurish/.rvm and other rvm traces?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
Removing rvm-shipped binaries (rvm-prompt, rvm, rvm-sudo rvm-shell and rvm-auto-ruby)
Removing rvm wrappers in /Users/gaurish/.rvm/bin
Hai! Removing /Users/gaurish/.rvm
```

This will remove RVM & its entire from your path.

ANd if you want to keep rvm or have already removed it manually. Now, just want to get rid of the rvm related entries from PATH. find this line which is responsible for adding rvm to your path:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

using grep

```
$ grep -nr 'PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting' ~
```

Now, you will have the list of files along with line number that contain this line. you can ignore any entries in history. Mainly focus on entires in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.zshrc` and other config files. And remove each of those